# Google App Engine - The engine "node" is incompatible with this module

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, deployment

This questions has been asked many times already, and I checked all the answers but none of them helped me.

I'm trying to deploy a NodeJs app to GAE using a app.yml file. It was working perfectly until my last Github PR on it where I upgraded some nodes modules.

Now I'm getting the Error `The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "16.x.x". Got "12.19.0"`.

As you can see I'm up to date on my computer. I also removed and install Node, Npm and Yarn tonight just to be sure.

```
node -v
v16.15.0
npm -v
8.5.5
yarn -v
1.22.18
```

I tried deploying the app with a specific node version on my packages.json but with or without it's not working.

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x.x"
  },
```

I also tried to remove the cache on GAE using this, without no effect.

```
default_expiration: '0d 0h'
```

On my app.yml I'm using `nodejs` en `Env: flex`:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
```

I can't use `node16` as I need `env: flex`.

Of course I tried to delete the Node_modules and yarn.lock for at least 100 times but still nothing, always the same error.

Nothing change on the app.yml file since the last deployment. The only thing is that I upgraded some Node Modules.

On the Yarn side I've tried:

```
yarn install --force
yarn install --ignore-engines
yarn cache clean --all
```

But still not working.

Any help will be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The error is because the image used by google is fixed to the version 12.19.0, check [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docker/blob/master/runtime-image/Dockerfile#L24-L28) for more info.

My workaround was use a custom image:

1. Change in the `app.yaml` file the runtime to `custom`.

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
...
```

2. Create a `Dockerfile` file with the following content:

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/nodejs

# Current Node LTS version.
RUN /usr/local/bin/install_node '16.16.0'

RUN npm install --unsafe-perm --global yarn

COPY . /app/

RUN yarn install --production || \
  ((if [ -f yarn-error.log ]; then \
      cat yarn-error.log; \
    fi) && false)
CMD yarn start
```